# Crystal Report graphs dont appear

Tags: graph, crystal-reports

I create a graph with Crystal Report, but when I execute on client site in debug, I cannot see the grathic; only if I export to PDF the result of the query appairs and I can see the image of the graph.
The same if I publish on the server. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I solved by myself the problem.

I added in WebConfig this configurations:

•   In system. webServer tag I added this

```
<handlers><add name="CrystalImageHandler.aspx_GET" verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx"
type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler,
CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" /></handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

•   In system.web tag I added this

```
<httpHandlers><add verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/></httpHandlers>
```

In IIS ( in Editor configurations of the site) i allowed the handler in this section system.webServer/handlers